# Prolog programming - what is the program regarding the next tasks?

Tags: prolog, logic

**Could you help me regarding the next three Prolog programs?**

1. Summary of the elements in a list, and check that is divided or not divided with 3? 
   *For example, the list is [1, 2, 3] --> and the sum of the element is divided with 3, because 1+2+3=6, and 6/3=2 --> so the output should be true.*
2. If the 7 is in a list, doubles it. *For example: the input list --> [1,7,3,7,7], the outputs should be [1,7,7,3,7,7,7,7].*
3. If the 7 is in a list, change it for 2,7,2. *For example: the input list -->[1,7,2,1], the output should be [1,2,7,2,2,1]*

What is the program and how to test it with SWI-Prolog?

Thank you in anticipation!

Comment: This is not domyhomeworkforme.com.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a couple of tips:

1. You need a) to calculate the sum, b) check whether it divides by 3. If you use SWI-Prolog there is a predicate `sum_list` in the library `lists` that does a) and the `... is ... mod ...` construction to solve b) If you need to use recursion rather than the built-in predicate to calculate the sum:

   > sum([X|Xs], Acc, Sum) :- Acc1 is Acc + X, sum(Xs, Acc1, Sum).
   >
   > sum([], Acc, Acc).
   >
   > sum(List, Sum) :- sum(List, 0, Sum).
2. and 3. These are recursive procedures. You should traverse the list and if 7 is encountered you should replace it with 7,7 for question 2 and with 2,7,2 for question 3.

> ```
> traverse_list([],[]).
> traverse_list([7|Xs], [7,7|Ps]) :-
>    !,
>    traverse_list(Xs,Ps).
> traverse_list([X|Xs], [X|Ps]) :-
>    traverse_list(Xs,Ps).
> ```

Think about modifying this fragment for 3.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the codes. Regarding my 2 and 3 question: If I understand well, your code wait for two list (for example: [1,1,7] and [1,1,7,7]) and the output is true or false (in the example is true). But a code is needed for me, where the input is [1,1,7] and the output is [1,1,7]!  So only one list is needed and the code creates the other one. Could you help me?

Comment: Predicate `traverse_list` can also be called with the second argument being a variable. Upon success the variable will be unified with the list where all 7 have been duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend giving it a little thought and figuring it out on your own. That said, I'll give you something to help get started:

1) I'm assuming your instructor wants to see you do the recursion rather than use the built-in sum_list predicate. That would look something like this:

sum([FirstNum | Rest], Sum) :-
    sum(Rest, Sum1),
    Sum is FirstNum + Sum1.

Then use the "mod" operator to check divisibility. Remember to include a base case for when the recursion reaches the empty set []. If you can understand this, the rest should be easy.  Good luck.

Comment: If recursion is used, it is more efficient to use tail-recursion (= recursive call is the last subgoal in the clause's body). Tail-recursive implementation can be done using the accumulator: `sum([X|Xs], Acc, Sum) :- Acc1 is Acc + X, sum(Xs, Acc1, Sum).`, `sum([], Acc, Acc).` and `sum(List, Sum) :- sum(List, 0, Sum).`

Comment: Agreed... but maybe not the easiest conceptually for a beginner. Computational Complexity vs. Homework Problem Complexity :D